# Selectively Binding Data To a Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I want to selectively bind data in a collection to different UI elements. For instance I have a collection of objects where each object has a property which describes the type of that object. I am currently using a DataTemplate to categorise the elements. But when I bidnd the collection to two different UI containers despite DataTemplates are available the objects get added to both the containers. Following code will make the question more clearer:

View:

Data Templates:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ColumnDataTemplate">
        <Label DataContext="{Binding ColumnDiscriptor}" Foreground="White" Background="DarkOrange" BorderThickness="5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnName}">
            <!--<Run Text="{Binding TableName}"/><Run Text="."/><Run Text="{Binding ColumnName}"/>-->
            </TextBlock>
        </Label>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ControllerDataTemplate">
        <Label Content="{Binding OperatorValue}" Foreground="White" Background="Crimson" BorderThickness="5">
        </Label>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueDataTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ComparedValue, Mode= TwoWay}" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="46" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="JoinDataTemplate">
            <Grid>
            <!--<Run Text="{Binding TableName}"/><Run Text="."/><Run Text="{Binding ColumnName}"/>-->
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding ColumnDiscriptor}" Foreground="Black" Background="Brown" BorderThickness="5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnName}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding JoinWithColumnDescriptor}" Foreground="Black" Background="Beige" BorderThickness="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ColumnName}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

 <local:QueryObjectDataTemplateSelector x:Key="ModelSelector"
                                       ColumnTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnDataTemplate}"
                                       ControllerTemplate="{StaticResource ControllerDataTemplate}"
                                       ValueTemplate="{StaticResource ValueDataTemplate}"
                                       />
```

UI Containers:

```
<ListBox  Height="146" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,38,0,0" Name="visulaqueryPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="344" Background="#18EBEBE2" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Item_Drop" DragEnter="Item_DragEnter"  ItemsSource="{Binding ViewUIElements}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapPanelTemplate}" 
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ModelSelector}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDesignerVisualQueryObject}"/>

<ListBox AllowDrop="True" Background="#1CFFFFFF" Margin="10,38,6,39" Name="grid1" Drop="Join_Item_Drop" DragEnter="Item_DragEnter" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewUIElements}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource JoinDataTemplate}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDesignerVisualQueryObjectJoin}" />
```

According to my problem ViewUIElemetns is the collection which consist of the objects which are of different types.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just define different DataTemplates based on the Type:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SomeType1}">
 ...
</DataTemplate> 

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SomeType2}">
 ...
</DataTemplate>
```

if you have to do it by Property and not by type, then u should use DataTemplateSelector:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: Hi Elad, thank you very much for the answer. But it is not very clear to me. If possible could you relate the answer to the code I provided? I am wandering as to how I can use a string property withing an object of a collection could be used as a type parameter; I am confused. Thanks again.

Comment: Doing it based on type is better IMO, but if you have to select based on a property, then i suggest using DataTemplateSelector http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: Elad, got it working. I have already been using a data template selector and utilized it not to show unwanted content off the collection it is bound to. Thank you very much for your great support. If you get any chance please edit your answer to reflect the real solution for other's use, as I am marking the question as answered. Thanks again.